# How do I keep track of invisible/hidden targets

Tags: combat, 13th-age

The upcoming fight which I am designing takes place in the sewers, with many twists and bends. 13th Age does not use a battle grid or count squares per se, but keep track of the distance combatants using 3 abstract ranges - engaged, nearby and faraway.

What I wish to accomplish is something of a 'cat and mouse' chase, as the party try to run away from a big bad monster, they run into smaller ones along the way. What will happen is as the party runs, they will lose sight of enemies, due to the twist and bends of the tunnels. How do I keep track of where those enemies are without letting the players know, so that I can surprise them?

Answer (score 4):

Given that the system encourages a less grounded style of play I would leave it up to your own discretion when the enemies should encounter the players. While not as helpful an answer as I would like to give. However, I think that you can create a much more intense experience if you aim to create a mood of uncertainty for your players as they dash through the maze of tunnels not knowing what will be around the next corner. And when you think that you have built up enough tension have them run into the big bad. Also, the instead of spending time tracking the exact movement of enemies you can spend it on gauging your players reactions to how the encounter is going and determine if around the next corner is an empty tunnel, a lowly thug, a villainous rogue or your big bad. Hope this helps, and good luck with your encounter!